# Что значит "комбинированный алгоритм для её обслуживания"?

Tags: алгоритм

> Задание. Необходимо реализовать очередь на базе списков, применяя
>   комбинированный алгоритм для ее обслуживания. Затем 
>   продемонстрировать выполнение основных операций с элементами очереди:
>   поиск, добавление, удаление.

Необходим некоторый пример для ясности как реализовать список используя комбинированный алгоритм обслуживания.

Comment: А это вы лучше спросите у того, кто писал это задание.

Comment: Фраза вырвана из контекста, поэтому сложно понять, что именно имеется ввиду. Добавьте больше информации. В каком контексте это было сказано?

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC&lr=2 - почитайте про комбинированный алгоритм, и реализуйте очередь в базе списков с его помощью.

Comment: ОМГ, где-то до сих пор разделяют алгоритмы по этим типам...

Comment: http://www.cyberforum.ru/delphi-beginners/thread1466486.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Мне кажется, что, в данном случае, имеется в виду, что надо использовать несколько алгоритмов, например для поиска:

```
Class list {
  function search(element) {
    if(this.size > 100){
       //ищем делением пополам например исходя из того что при добавлении мы храним отсортированный массив
    }
    else {
    //ищем простым перебором т.к. для малого количества это будет быстре
    }
  }
//аналогично для добавления, удаления, используем разное поведение в зависимости от контекста
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Существуют несколько алгоритмов обработки очередей:
>
> - традиционный алгоритм FIFO;
> - приоритетное обслуживание (Priority Queuing), которое также называют «подавляющим»;
> - взвешенные очереди (Weighted Queuing);
> - взвешенное справедливое обслуживание (Weighted Fair Queuing, WFQ).
>
> Возможно комбинированное применение этих алгоритмов.

[(ref)](http://masters.donntu.org/2011/fkita/ryadskaya/diss/index.htm)

WFQ - это уже комбинация, сочетающая приоритетное обслуживание очередей с взвешенным. Возможно от Вас просят реализацию данной очереди. Коротко, элементы очереди это конечный набор списков с наперёд заданным весом обслуживания и один список, который всегда обслуживается первым (другие списки очереди обслуживаются по весу только если этот список пуст).

Answer (score 1):

*Немного теории:*

Есть различные методы по реализации работы с очередями, такие как:

приоритетное обслуживание - обеспечивает минимальный уровень задержек для очереди наивысшего приоритета, но не дает никаких гарантий в отношении средней пропускной способности для трафика очередей более низких приоритетов.

Взвешенное обслуживание - обеспечивает заданное распределение средней пропускной способности, но не учитывает требований к задержкам.

И тут приходит на помощь - **комбинированный алгоритм обслуживания**. В алгоритме подобного рода поддерживается одна приоритетная очередь, а остальные очереди обслуживаются в соответствии со взвешенным алгоритмом. Обычно приоритетная очередь используется для чувствительного к задержкам трафика, а остальные — для эластичного трафика (тип трафика, поддерживаемый IP-сетями) нескольких классов. Каждый класс эластичного трафика получает некоторый минимум пропускной способности при перегрузках. Этот минимум вычисляется как процент от пропускной способности, оставшейся от приоритетного трафика.

Для более детального погружения в данную область, прикладываю ссылку на источник  [Моделирование алгоритмов обслуживания очередей...](http://informika.ru/files/contentfile/377/12-p29.pdf)

Возможно источник не 100% попадет в твою задачу и не все из этого тебе понадобится, но само понимание и принцип работы описан.

Answer (score 0):

Главная очередь обслуживается пока не пуста, все остальное время распределяется между очередями по приоритету.

Сперва обслуживается очередь с самым высоким приоритетом.

За каждую операцию приоритет очереди снижается на определенное стрессовое значение по отношению к остальным очередями, которое расчитывается в зависимости от отношения суммарного количества всех элементов к суммарному количеству элементов в данной очереди, т.е. чем больше доля потока очереди - тем меньше стрессовое значение.

Допустим есть 3 очереди(кроме главной) с потоком в 10, 5 и 1 элемент в единицу времени. соответсвующее стрессовое значение 1.6, 3.2 и 16, т.о. каждая очередь будет обрабатываться пропорционально потоку.
А если заполнять очереди 1 раз, то все очереди закончатся примерно в одно и то же время.

Есть вариант задать фиксированное стрессовое значение заранее, но тогда придется ограничить разницу приоритетов между очередями.

Answer (score 0):

**Комбинированный алгоритм для её обслуживания** означает что нужно использовать смешанный алгоритм для совмещения достоинств разных алгоритмов.

Например, при передачи данных по сети требуется отдавать приоритет передачи важным данным. Например нужных для обслуживания самой сети, о передающихся пакетах итп. Или команда отмена загрузки должна уйти раньше чем придёт видео. Второй приоритет - текстовые данные. А картинки с видео можно загрузить в последнюю очередь. При этом очередь на передачу картинок будет формироваться другим алгоритмом отдельно, например сначала верхние или сначала маленькие. При этом ещё может работать отдельный алгоритм распределения % трафика, между этими данными или разными компьютерами.

[Пример 2](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0ahUKEwjbzbupv6TUAhVJDZoKHUSmCCAQFghEMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstudhelp.net%2Forder%2Fdownloadfile%2F19256&usg=AFQjCNHT7hL0QQK4lOITajLjNjBVyKtTRg&cad=rjt):

Есть алгоритм: «очередь с приоритетом» предполагает, что объекты, требующие обработки, ставятся в очередь, а извлекаются из нее не в порядке занесения, а согласно приоритету. 
       Алгоритмы приоритетного обслуживания очень популярны во многих областях вычислительной техники, в частности в ОС, когда одним приложениям нужно отдать предпочтение перед другими при их обработке в мультипрограммной смеси. Весь трафик разбивается на небольшое количество классов, каждому из которых присваивается приоритет. Приоритетное обслуживание обычно применяется для класса трафика, чувствительного к задержкам, имеющего небольшую интенсивность. Тогда обслуживание этого класса не слишком ущемляет остальные классы. Например, голосовой трафик (чувствителен, но его интенсивность обычно не превышает 8-16 Кбит/c).
       Альтернативой приоритетному обслуживанию являются взвешенные очереди. Они гарантируют всем классам трафика определенный минимум пропускной способности. Под весом понимается процент предоставляемой классу трафика пропускной способности от полной пропускной способности выходного интерфейса. С каждой очередью связывается процент пропускной способности ресурса, гарантируемый ему при перегрузках этого ресурса.

**Совмещение достоинств приоритетных и взвешенных очередей удается получить в комбинированных алгоритмах.** Обычно в них используется одна приоритетная очередь для чувствительного трафика, а остальные обслуживаются в соответствии с взвешенным алгоритмом. Им выделяется часть интенсивности ресурса, оставшегося от приоритетной очереди.